# How to create custom timezone with custom DST settings using an NTP server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, dst, ntp

I have few NTP servers that I use with multiple platforms (Ubuntu, RHEL etc). I have many machines pointing to these servers and time is synced up as expected. I need to create a custom time-zone on the NTP server such that I am able to manipulate the DST settings for this timezone? I.e. need to have the ability to perform Spring/Fall DST on any specific date on as needed basis.

Is this even possible?

Comment: NTP distributes UTC (also known as GMT), without any time zones applied.  Normally, time zones are applied on each machine (actually, in every process on every machine) that wants to display a local time.  Normally, if you wanted a bunch of machines to have the same time zone, you'd make sure they were all configured the same (for example, all had the same `/etc/localtime` file).

Comment: If you want to create your own time zone, springing forward or falling back according to your own custom schedule (not any of the many standard ones), you can create your own "zoneinfo" file, and compile it using the `zic` program.  (And then you would either install the new file as `/etc/localtime`, or install it under `/usr/share/zoneinfo` and have `/etc/localtime` be a symlink pointing to it.)

Comment: If would help if you explained *why* you want to create a custom time zone (is it for a specific region, which one?  Or because of some custom business rules, or something else?)  But clearly this is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), since TZ and NTP are not related.  It's also off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question - NTP has no concept of time zones [[1]](https://www.meinbergglobal.com/english/faq/faq_32.htm) nor DST [[2]](https://www.meinbergglobal.com/english/faq/faq_33.htm), that is down to the underlying OS/Subsystem.

NTP simply serves up the time & date in UTC.

Not sure what your usage case is - but you would need to either look at doing what you want at OS level, or simply running everything in sync to your own version of UTC. (As in you could have a closed time domain, serve the time from 1 server and manipulate it as you wish slow it down or speed it up etc.)

Comment: Maintaining a "closed" NTP time domain works if you only want to speed it up or slow it down by a second or two.  If you tried to jump a master NTP time server forward or backwards by an hour, it would be hugely disruptive, and it would take some time (typically 20-40 minutes to a couple of hours) for all the other machines to sync up, so it would be useless for coordinated DST transitions.

Comment: Yes that's very true - you could slow over a very long period I guess but it would be a mess if any system was connected to 'the real world' I'd never advocate jumping backwards in any time domain - it breaks too many things!

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with every answer here. NTP server itself has no concept of time-zones. As pointed above, I was able to get the latest tzdata from their FTP repo. Manually edited the 'northamerica' file in VI to change the DST rules. Saved and compiled using zic. This [link](https://www.borngeek.com/2009/03/16/updating-time-zone-information-in-linux/) is also very useful.